# How to create Geofencing?

Tags: android, geofencing

i want to create Geo Fencing in my application and get a notification if I am outside the Geo Fence. Can you guys tell me if i receive incoming messages except coordinates? I want to get notification rather than my maps activity start.

**Code in my Activity:**

```
package biketracker1.com.biketracker;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private String getLangs;
  private String [] getValues;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
   Intent intent = getIntent();

  getLangs = intent.getExtras().getString("messages");
  getValues = getLangs.split(",");

   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
 }


  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

 LatLng sydney = new  LatLng(Double.parseDouble(getValues[0]),Double.parseDouble(getValues[1]));

 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Lahore"));
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? What intent data are you being sent?

Comment: try this tutorials................... https://dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps

Comment: and also this............https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/implementing-map-and-geofence-features-in-android-business-apps